# does spring has a class for implementing 'temporary storage'?

Tags: java, spring

I need to implement a sth like temporary storage in java spring app. For example, when event happens, I put there a value, but the same time this class is being listened by another listener class, and as soon as needed value comes to this `storage`, listener invokes certail action. How to implement it in java and spring? Currently I use ConcurrentHashMap for that, are there better solutions?

Comment: You are looking for JMS is what i think.

Comment: You might want to use EventBus from guava - see http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.html

Comment: Thank you, how do you think is jms will be faster than listening map? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your listener classes are within same application,observer pattern is what you should use. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm

If your listener classes are outside application, you should use messaging queues, something like JMS.

Comment: Thank you, this is the most applicable solution but there an issue is clients are waiting in the http request for this event. And I still need sth like map to listen and put messages there, sth like intermediate bus. And this is an issue as I need to sleep in a loop, and it reduces performance incredibly, I can`t use an infinite loop, I need to terminate it if I get no response at all.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, Spring does not provide any thing like that.

1) You could use JMS (example: Active MQ etc...)

(or)

2) Any framework that supports event modeling such as [Axon Framework.](http://www.axonframework.org/)